# How to get the location of head bone relative to parent's head bone

Tags: scripting, bones

In my python script I want to get the location of the head of the bone, in the parent's local matrix. This means that the equation:

```
b.head_local = b.parent_n.local_matrix * .... * b.parent.local_matrix * searched
```

I know `bone.head` but it seems this is **sometimes** relative to the **tail** of the parent. I say **sometimes** because I can't figure out **when** this is the case.

Can someone help me out with this? An alternative way to get the searched coordinates would help out as well.

**EDIT:** *I don't understand the variables that blender offers on bones at all. None of them except `bone.head_local` and `bone.tail_local`. If someone could explain them that would be honorable.*

Comment: Do you want to get the position?

Comment: The position in the parent's matrix aka. `parmatrix * pos = somepos` and if that pos is then again multiplied with the parent's parent, etc... until no parent exists that position would be the armature-local position